# How to show/hide a sidebar based on a button press and screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I built a custom nav sidebar for my panel. Inside this sidebar i have few menu options. When my screen size is small, i want all menu options to dissapear, and show only one especific menu item. This especific menu option is used like a button that you can use to make all itens appear again.

The menu:

[image]

When my screen is small it looks like this:

[image]

For my sidebar menu i use the code bellow:

```
<div class="card-body">

<a id="shmenulinks" class="nav-link" style="border-radius: 0.25rem; cursor: pointer; width: 100%;" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menulinks" data-target="#menulinks"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Open/Close menu</a>

<div id="menulinks" class="nav nav-pills" >
<a style="width: 100%;" href="https://codepen.io/" target="blank" class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
<a style="width: 100%;" href="https://codepen.io/" target="blank" class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Projects</a>
<a style="width: 100%;" href="https://codepen.io/" target="blank" class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Jobs</a>
<a style="width: 100%;" href="https://codepen.io/" target="blank" class="nav-link "><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
</div>

</div>
```

To make the menu options appear/disappear i use this CSS logic bellow:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

#shmenulinks {
display: none;
}
#menulinks {
display: block;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
#shmenulinks {
display: block;
}
#menulinks {
display: none;
}

}
```

**My problem is when my screen is small and my menu is collapsed, the button that can be used to make the menu options appear/disappear doesn't work.**

The CODEPEN:
https://codepen.io/neyelson-alves/pen/ZEGbdJB

What should i do?

Comment: for such issue, best is to share a fiddle or link,

Comment: can u plz share this in codepen?

Comment: codepen template added, pls help

Answer (score 2):

Please Add jquery.

```
$("#shmenulinks").click(function(){ $("#menulinks").slideToggle();});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: JQuery was already added, but i'm not using javascript since i don't know a javascript solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are classes available to use display properties for all the breakpoints. If you want to hide some menus only in Medium devices use the class ** d-lg-block d-md-none d-sm-block**
You want to show all the menus in large and medium devices expect in mobile you can use like class=" **  d-lg-block d-md-block d-none d-sm-none** " 
I have put it for div similarly u give the classes to the element you want to hide only in small screens (Mobile) or Medium Devices(Tablet)

```
<div class="col-sm-4 d-lg-block d-md-block d-none d-sm-none ">
  <h3>Column 1</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
</div>
```

On button click call a function and do like this

```
function onBtnClick(){
var element = document.getElementById("Menu1");
element.classList.add("d-lg-block d-md-block d-none d-sm-none");
}
```

Comment: If you check my codepen template, you will see that the menu options already disappear when i'm in a small screen size. The problem is that i cannot make them appear again with a button press.

Comment: you try to implement method to add classes to make it displayed on button click event (Button Press ).

Comment: Even if add classes to make it appear again, the CSS media won't allow the menu options to appear since the screen width is too small.

Comment: Please update this in your code . It works
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

    #shmenulinks {
      display: block;
    }
    .nav-link-collapse.not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
    $(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
  });

  }

Answer (score 1):

Please update your media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

#shmenulinks {
  display: block;
}
.nav-link-collapse.not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
$(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
});

}
```

Comment: Not sure if i did it correctly, but I guess that your solution doesn't make the menu options to disappear automatically when the screen size is small.

Comment: When I checked its disappearing automatically when the screen size is small

Comment: Can u just remove this from the above mentioned update and check ? 
}); above the last curly braces.